# Java 8 Filter Values from a Specific Column in Collection

Tags: java

I have a `List<DataBean>` where the bean is defined as follows,

```
private int id;
private int activityId;
private String info;
private int answerCode;
private String otherData;
```

There is another List with a different bean, `List<Answer>`, with the bean as follows:

```
   private int id;
   private int code;
```

I need to find all Answers in `List<Answer>` whose `code` is contained in the column `List<DataBean>.answerCode`.

**Example:**

`List<DataBean>` contains

```
id  activityId  info answerCode
1   1           ..   144
1   1           ..   153
1   2           ..   160
1   3           ..   177
```

`List<Answer>` contains

```
id  code
--------
1   160
2   161
```

Therefore, my result from `List<Answer>` is just one:   `1  160`.

Comment: Have you tried writing some code to do this?

Comment: `answers.stream().filter(a -> data.stream().anyMatch(d -> d.code == a.answerCode)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @shmosel: Your solution is nice and compact but inefficient as it has a runtime of O(n^2).

Comment: @Robert You mean O(n*m).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// List<DataBean> -> Set<Integer> (set of answer codes)
Set<Integer> set = beans.stream()
                        .map(DataBean::getAnswerCode)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

// List<Answer> -> filtered List<Answer>
List<Answer> result = answers.stream()
                             .filter(a -> set.contains(a.getCode()))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do that this way:

```
List<Answer> userAnswers = answers.stream()
        .filter(answer -> users.stream().anyMatch(user -> 
             user.answerCode==answer.code))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Works but is painfully slow for large data sets because it's runtime is  O(n^2)